# Is ARMA fit well-defined?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, arima, linear-model, identifiability

My question is whether unique time series has a unique set of ARMA parameters that fit it best, once order of AR and MA have been chosen.

For simplicity, I will ask only about ARMA(1,1) process. Lets say I have time series $\{x_t\}_{t=0\dots N-1}$. I can define the lag operator as a matrix:

$$
L=\left(\begin{array}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
\dots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

where $L^k=0$ for all $k\ge N$. Then

$$
L\left(\begin{array}\\x_{N-1} \\ x_{N-2}\\ \dots\\ x_1 \\ x_0 \end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}\\ x_{N-2} \\ x_{N-3} \\ \dots\\ x_0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right).
$$

With this, I can describe ARMA process as one that fits

$$
\left(1-\alpha\cdot L\right)\left(\begin{array}\\x_{N-1} \\ x_{N-2}\\ \dots\\ x_1 \\ x_0 \end{array}\right)=\left(1-\theta\cdot L\right)\left(\begin{array}\\n_{N-1} \\ n_{N-2}\\ \dots\\ n_1 \\ n_0 \end{array}\right)
$$

with $-1<\theta,\alpha<1$ and $n_{\dots}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\,1\right)$ being iid normal variables.

Under these conditions $\left(1-\alpha\cdot L\right)$ and $\left(1-\theta\cdot L\right)$ are invertible so I can also write:

$$
\left(1-\theta\cdot L\right)^{-1}\cdot\left(1-\alpha\cdot L\right)\left(\begin{array}\\x_{N-1} \\ x_{N-2}\\ \dots\\ x_1 \\ x_0 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}\\n_{N-1} \\ n_{N-2}\\ \dots\\ n_1 \\ n_0 \end{array}\right).
$$

It would therefore seem that if time series $x_{t}$ is normally distributed already, i.e. $x_t\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\,1\right)$ irrespective of time, then any combination of $\theta=\alpha$ parameters will fit the solution. If I tried to fit $\alpha,\theta$ using maximum likelihood in such case, it would seem that optimizer would have an infinite number of equally valid solutions (though some may behave better numerically).

I am guessing this problem will only become more obvious as the order of the time-series grows. How is this problem normally solved? Is there expectation for ARMA constants to be well-defined given the time-series?

Comment: *if time series $x_t$ is normally distributed already, i.e. it is simply noise...* How do you define "simply noise" and why is the type of distribution (normal vs. nonnormal) relevant?

Comment: @RichardHardy I meant if $x_t\sim N\left(0,\,1\right)$ already, irrespective of time.

Comment: Are you asking whether ARMA(p,q) always leads to a unique process? The answer is NO. Different specifications ARMA(p,q) and ARMA(p1,q1) may lead to the same process.

Comment: @Aksakal. That helps thanks. Are there any widely used approaches to constraining ARMA problems in order to arrive at unique values? For example, I could think of first fitting AR(p), then constraining those weights and fitting MA(q). At the very least, I would imagine this could help by making it faster (or more efficient) to fit ARMA.

Comment: make sure the estimated process is causal and invertible. your stat package may do it for you already

Comment: @Aksakal, isn't it causal by definition, i.e. through use of lag operators? What does invertible means in this context? $(1-\alpha L)^{-1}$ exists for all $\alpha$ in case of finite-dimensional lag operators (though for $\left|\alpha\right|>1$ there might be numerical problems). I am not using any specialized packages, simply optimizer to optimize based on max likelihood (optax adam in this case)

Comment: Searching for 'causality' in the context of ARIMA does give results, [stats.libretexts.org](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Advanced_Statistics/Time_Series_Analysis_(Aue)/3%3A_ARMA_Processes/3.2%3A_Causality_and_Invertibility) and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531338/what-is-a-causal-process-in-time-series-analysis, but those seem to be conditions for the time-series themselves, i.e. a condition on whether time-series can be modeled with ARIMA. What I was wondering about is, once we have decided that we can model the process with ARIMA, ....

Comment: are there any regularization techniques to constrain the excessive freedom in the coefficients?

Comment: From this thread (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197803/inverting-arma-processes) it seems that invertability it about finding inverse for the polynomials in lag operator, e.g. $1-aL+bL^2+\dots$. But can't I extend the roots of the polynomials to complex numbers and then always have a way to factorize the polynomial (by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)?

Comment: you can represent AR(p) process as MA(q) process, but sometimes you need error terms from future to do it. so, when you restrict the processes to causal you allow only error terms from the past. e.g. $x_t=1.1 x_{t-1}+e_t$ is a stationary process but it's not causal

Comment: @Aksakal, I really appreciate your advice, I hope you don't mind answering few more questions. Regarding your example $x_t-1.1\cdot x_{t-1}=e_t$. How is it not causal? The present ($x_t$) depends on the past ($x_{t-1}$). I guess it is anomalous in that the influence of the past will grow the further back you go in the past (i.e. $x_{t-3}$ will have a bigger effect on $x_{t}$ than $x_{t-2}$). Is that what you mean by not causal? The fact that this type of process cannot be stable in the long-term?

Comment: let's convert it into MA process. $x_{t-1}=1/1.1x_t-1/1.1e_t$ if you keep recursively applying this equation you'll see that $x_t=-\sum_{j=1}^\infty e_{t+j}/1.1^j$ - this looks like a nice weakly stationary linear process. the only problem is that all errors are from future. so it's not causal

Comment: @Aksakal, so the logic is as follows - direction of time for purposes of causality is one in which the process can be stationary, hence in your example the direction in which the process can be stationary is $x_t\to x_{t-1}$, which goes in the opposite direction to the one implied by sub-scripts, hence issues with causality? It would then seem that as long as the coefficients in front of lag operators that act on $x_t$, i.e. $\alpha$-s in my original post are below one by module, there would be no issues with causality, as per this definition?

Comment: i.e. the restrictions sufficient to satisfy causality would be $-1<\alpha<1$

Comment: for AR(1) process to be stationary $\alpha\ne 1$ but to be causal $\alpha<1$. the "direction" is not the concept from time series analysis. I know it's a weird notion that the errors come from future. think of it as a math trick. generally you write ARMA as $\phi(B)x_t=\theta(B)e_t$, so you can represent it either as AR or as MA, e.g. $x_t=\phi^{-1}(B)\theta(B)e_t$

Comment: so you get into weird situation sometimes like ARMA(2,1) process: $x_t=1/4x_{t-2}+e_t+1/2e_{t-1}$. in this case the polynomials have a common root because $1-1/4=(1-1/2)(1+1/2)$, so the process is really AR(1): $x_t=1/2x_{t-1}+e_t$, i.e. we have different set of coefficients that produce the same process

Comment: Aksakal & Richard - thank you